# Will the HTC Thunderbolt be able to use AT&T's network?

Tags: htc-thunderbolt, mobile-network

I'm speaking from a hardware perspective. It supports the 850 and 1900 network bands that AT&T uses, but will it work? The phone is amazing, absolutely destroys the Inspire 4G (which is a complete joke in my opinion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  [It's a CDMA phone](http://www.htc.com/us/products/thunderbolt-verizon#tech-specs) using 800 and 1900 mhz bands. CDMA phones can't be used on GSM networks (AT&T, Tmobile...). GSM and CDMA are completely different technologies.

Comment: We don't do shopping recommendations here but if we did and I was on AT&T I'd get the [Atrix](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Motorola-ATRIX-4G_id4982).

Comment: Nope. I'm currently running a N1 and I ain't sacrificing my freedom for a Motorola. Plus the Atrix is only a 4.0 inch screen. What I'm really looking for is a 4.3" screen, front-facing camera, 4G, kickstand, and 8-32GB onboard memory with a SD card :)

Comment: @TK Check out the Samsung Galaxy S2 phones due soon, or the Vibrant 4G just out.

Comment: Bad luck. AT&T quote-on-quote "4G" is merely an upgraded 3G network (HSPA+), not actual 4G (LTE or WiMax)
The Atrix runs Android, so no different from the Thunderbolt except no HTC Sense dumped on top of Android.